# How can I import a simple json dataset into memgraph

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I have read all information about importing json but find that documentation poor. The memgraph docs say, just do this:

```
CALL json_util.load_from_url("https://download.memgraph.com/asset/mage/data.json") 
YIELD objects
UNWIND objects AS o
RETURN o.first_name AS name, o.last_name AS surname;
```

But that does not do it, because a typical json graph dataset has several properties holding nodes and links with arbitrary properties:

```
{
   nodes: [ ... ],
   links: [ ... ],
   ...
}
```

So we need to access these properties and we need to create nodes with all properties of the imported objects. I cant find any documentation on how to do this. I finally managed to create nodes inside memgraph with the correct type ("ENTITY") but do not see how I can assign those nodes *all* properties from the imported json data:

```
CALL json_util.load_from_path("/data.json")
YIELD objects              // "objects" is the named result from the function above
UNWIND objects as o        // create a list of the properties of the imported result, which is a single object in my case and in most cases
UNWIND o.nodes as n        // select the nodes and return them as list
CREATE (e:ENTITY { id:n.id }) // all nodes will have 1 property, "id"
RETURN e
```

All nodes will have 1 property, "id", but I need all properties. How is this done. Where is the documentation or the book that explains that?

In javascript I would write

```
    CREATE (e:ENTITY { ...n })
```

How is this done in Cypher? Or how can this done in memgraph with another language or tool?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `json_util.load_from_path` procedure, then you have to **specify each of the properties you want to write to the database**, just like in the example in [Memgraph docs](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/next/import-data/files/load-json#load-json-from-a-local-file):

```
CALL json_util.load_from_path("path/to/data.json")
YIELD objects
UNWIND objects AS o
CREATE (:Person {first_name: o.first_name, last_name: o.last_name, pets: o.pets});
```

The above procedure is expecting classic JSON, not structured in any particular way.

On the other hand, the [`import_util.json()`](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/python/import-util#jsonpath) procedure expects JSON to be in a specific format, structured the same as the JSON file that the [`export_util.json()`](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/python/export-util) procedure generates. Check the example in [Memgraph docs](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/python/import-util#example---importing-json-file-to-create-a-database).

If you wish to import your data in a way they are structured now, you need to use `json_util.load_from_path()` procedure and write down all of the properties you want to create in the database. Otherwise, you can structure your data appropriately for the `import_util.json()` procedure and import it that way. The construct you mentioned from the JavaScript is not supported in Cypher.

Let's suppose other properties you have in the JSON file are `name` and `last_name`. Then you would run this:

```
CALL json_util.load_from_path("/data.json")
YIELD objects              // "objects" is the named result from the function above
UNWIND objects as o        // create a list of the properties of the imported result, which is a single object in my case and in most cases
UNWIND o.nodes as n        // select the nodes and return them as list
CREATE (e:ENTITY { id:n.id, name: n.name, last_name: n.last_name }) 
RETURN e
```

We fixed the import docs in [the next version](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/next/import-data#json-files), and let me know if that's more clear now. Here is also the [JSON import subpage](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/next/import-data/files/load-json).

Comment: import_util.json() is perfect, i can easily reformat my json. Puno ti hvala ;)